# Knowrob reasoning about objects' tutorial error

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

\knowrob.org/doc/reasoning_about_objects

1. ratneshmadaan@ratneshmadaan-Inspiron-N5010:/$  roscd knowrob_basics_tutorial
2. ratneshmadaan@ratneshmadaan-Inspiron-N5010:~/rosbuild_ws/stacks/knowrob_tutorials/knowrob_basics_tutorial$

3 rd line(error):
?-  owl_parse('owl/ccrl2_map_objects.owl', false, false, true).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: owl_parse/4 (DWIM could not correct goal)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138716/knowrob-reasoning-about-objects%27-tutorial-error/) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake knowrob?

roscd knowrob?

**EDIT:**
This is a known bug in the binary .deb packages for Fuerte and Groovy. Neither of them are built any more, so there is no way to fix this problem. Please install KnowRob from source into your rosbuild workspace as described in the [Installation Guide](http://knowrob.org/installation).

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-03-11**:
Do I need to rosmake knowrob again? I already did that while installing the  knowrob system with tutorials.

And roscd knowrob? I did it. No difference

This is how it is here:
~/rosbuild_ws/stacks/knowrob
~/rosbuild_ws/stacks/knowrob_tutorials/knowrob_basics_tutorial

Is something wrong?
I first did the "basic knowrob installion" and then "KnowRob system including tutorials".

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-03-11**:
Oh! Have I made a big, bad blunder by not putting all this in /opt/ros/hydro ?

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-03-11**:
You shouldn't put things under /opt/ros. If your workspace is set up according to the tutorials, that's fine. roscd knowrob should bring you to the respective folder. Have you rosmade the knowrob_basics_tutorial package?

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-03-11**:
As I said, I was making a blunder; albeit a different one. Thank you.
And hats off for the thesis.

**Comment by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on 2014-08-12**:
Is this solved? I put the knowrob_basics_tutorial package in /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/ and I still get this error.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-08-13**:
As I said in my previous comment, you should NEVER put things in /opt/ros manually, but create a proper workspace in your home directory as described in the tutorials.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-08-13**:
If you use both catkin and rosbuild packages, you will need to create a combined workspace as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin#rosbuild_workspace_on_top_of_catkin_workspace).

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-08-13**:
If you then still have problems, please give details about your system setup (ROS version, Ubuntu version, swipl --version)

**Comment by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on 2014-08-13**:
I installed ros groovy on ubuntu 12.04. The version of swipl is SWI-Prolog version 5.10.4 for i386.
When I roscd knowrob I get /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/knowrob

**Comment by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on 2014-08-13**:
What I did was install knowrob like it said in the tutorial and this works fine. For the knowrob tutorials I used http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/StackInstallation#Using_GIT_to_pull_down_a_repository to install it from github in the opt/ros/groovy/stacks, where knowrob also is.

**Comment by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on 2014-08-13**:
In the git tutorial they assume you have installed ros from svn. But I have not and I don't know what the correct directories are in my case. I have a catkin workspace in my home folder. Should I install it there?

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-08-13**:
Have you installed KnowRob using apt-get? This is broken for ROS Groovy, as said in the [[installation instructions](http://knowrob.org/installation). The issue you described is a known [bug](https://github.com/knowrob/knowrob/issues/1) that cannot be fixed since the .deb are not built any more.

**Comment by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on 2014-08-13**:
Ok yes. I did miss that. I have now installed knowrob and the tutorials from source like the link showed. And both knowrob and knowrob_basics_tutorial are in /home/groovy_workspace/stacks and are found by roscd. But still I get the same error.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-08-13**:
Is /home/groovy_workspace a rosbuild or catkin workspace? knowrob is still a rosbuild stack. And have you run 'rosmake knowrob'? It should run without any error messages.

**Comment by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on 2014-08-13**:
It is a rosbuild stack using this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin and I have run rosmake knowrob and it showed me no errors.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-08-13**:
Hmm, no idea. We regularly install KnowRob without problems using the instructions on Ubuntu 12.04 which is our standard dev platform. It very likely is a problem of your ROS workspace setup, I'd double-check that ROS indeed uses the right version of KnowRob (e.g. uninstall the deb)